# Need stylesheet before ob_endflush() and before header(location: ), How?

Tags: php, css, header, styles

My page has the following structure:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ob_start();
?>

HTML HEADER
links to stylesheets global.css and mail.css

<?php
  function email(){
     /* using the stylesheets global.css and mail.css */
     $text = '<div class="test">
                 <p id="par">...
                    <span id="write" class="text">...</span>
                 </p>
              </div>';

     return $text;
  }
?>


/* some text and html stuff */

<?php
  if(isset(...)){
    /* php form validation */

    /* after validating I send an email to the user where I call
       the function email() which use the stylesheets. */
    $mail_text = 'Dear .....';
    $mail_text .= email();

    $mail_headers = "From: test@test.com\r\n".
                     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion().
                     'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
                     'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

     if(mail(..., ..., $mail_text, $mail_headers)){
         header('location: newlocation.php');
     }
?>

/* HTML FORMS and text and .... */

<?php
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The email is sent with the text coming from the email() function, but without formatting cause the CSS are "printed out" only after ob_end_flush() at the bottom of the page.

How could I solve that? There are many classes and styles inside email(), so writing every times `<div style="...">` and so on is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about output buffering. The html/css you print out at the start of the page isn't being captured anywhere, and will NOT be part of `$mail_text`. Just because you're usign output buffering doesn't make that buffer magically appear in a variable. You'd need at least `$mail_text .= ob_get_clean()` or something to extract the buffer's contents and put it into your variable.

Comment: $mail_text .= ob_get_contents();
call this before you call ob_get_clean();

Comment: This is excactly what I wrote, isn't it? "but without formatting cause the CSS are "printed out" only after ob_end_flush() at the bottom of the page."

Comment: yes, because ob_end_flush() dumps output to the client. that output is not stored in a variable. Your code has TWO output paths: email, and to the client browser. They're not in any way related, because you haven't done any code to link them.

Comment: don't build your own mime emails, especially when you're just starting out with PHP. Use phpmailer or swiftmailer. they make building html mails trivial.